# Install XP in a VM using an old (non-OEM) key

Tags: windows-xp, sony-vaio

So I have an old Sony VAIO lying around- older than me, in fact. It came with Windows Millenium, but it was upgraded to Windows XP Professional. The XP key I extracted from the registry is different from the Me key on the sticker, meaning I probably have a non-OEM key for Windows XP Pro. Is it possible to use that key to install Windows XP Pro in a VM (in Ubuntu) for the heck of it?

I can't really connect the VAIO to the internet, as its only networking ports are a telephone line and a firewire. It can't utilize any of my USB drives, and I have no way of writing to a floppy or CD disk from any other device (nor do I have any writable ones lying around). Is there still a way to disassociate the key to reuse it elsewhere?

Hardware in question: Sony VAIO PCG-F610 (https://docs.sony.com/release//pcgf610.pdf)

Comment: Why do you want to activate? Just create a snapshot and use it untill expire.

Comment: Don't really want to promote it but pirate the software ;)

Comment: @Biswapriyo Honestly, for the heck of it. I figured since I had the key, maybe there was a way to make use of it.

Comment: @RACING121 If I wanted to use Windows without a key, I'd be using 10, which I do have a valid copy of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming its a retail version it *should* work. I'm a little iffy about how long the activation servers would remain functional but I've never had to explicitly dissociate a copy of windows from a current install (and if its a  retail copy - you can move it, even if say the main system had multiple, major failures and was unbootable).

So... its possible, but the only way to be completely sure it'll work is to test it.

Comment: One possibility is it's an upgrade-only version/key. In that case you'd need to at least have install media for the older version (IIRC it doesn't check older version's key, nor does it actually have to be installed - but that's only on the technical side and this *might* be against the licence if you don't have a retail older version).

Comment: and off the information we have.... the only real way is to... test it? ;p

Comment: Would ignoring its warnings of unsupported drivers for newer USBs be okay? The entire system is only like 3 GB, so it'd easily fit on a thumb drive.

Comment: Its a VM. You're best off installing right off an ISO. I don't think you can simply copy off the whole OS and run it off a VM... unless you can find some p2v software or see if backing up and restoring works. That's a whole different problem though

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Funnily enough win10 and probably win8 generally work fine with the whole "copy off the whole OS" process. But XP is too old for the fancy newer hardware autodiscovery. Even 7 was a bit iffy.

Comment: @Bob Last I tried copying my OS to run on another device, it failed spectacularly. (Well, perhaps that's not the right word.) Fresh install worked fine, as did the old install when I put the source drive into the destination device. Error code was 0xc0[more 0s]0E. Real helpful, very specific.